# Trying to get the value of "Total" from JSON response

Tags: go, struct, pretty-print

**Response:**

{
"meta": {
"query_time": 0.039130201,
"pagination": {
"offset": 1345,
"limit": 5000,
"total": 1345
},

**Structs:**

type InLicense struct {
Total int16 `json:"total,omitempty"`
}

type OutLicense struct {
Pagination []InLicense `json:"pagination,omitempty"`
}

type MetaLicense struct {
Meta []OutLicense `json:"meta,omitempty"`
}

**Code snip inside function:**

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", , nil)
if err != nil {
//handle error
}

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
log.Println("Error: ", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
val := &MetaLicense{}

```
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&val)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, s := range val.Meta {
    for _, a := range s.Pagination {
        fmt.Println(a.Total)
    }

}
```

}

After I run this code I get the following error:
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field MetaLicense.meta of type []OutLicense

Which type would []OutLicense need to be in order for this to be unmarshaled correctly? I cant print it another way, but it prints with the {} and Strings.Trim will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use just a simple field declaration with actual type, not a `[]` of the type as it is done below:

```
type InLicense struct {
    Total int16 json:"total,omitempty"
}

type OutLicense struct {
     Pagination InLicense json:"pagination,omitempty"
}

type MetaLicense struct {
    Meta OutLicense json:"meta,omitempty"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried that, but when I do that I will not be able to range over val.Meta since it is not a slice.

Comment: @ioj The example of the JSON you provided doesn't contain JSON array, so nothing from it could be unmarshalled into the slice and that is why your code doesn't work. If you apply changes I suggested and remove the range over val.Meta it will work as expected

Comment: This solved my issue. The original way I was using to print it was way to messy and this simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the parsing a bit and just used the `json.Unmarshal()` function instead.

```
raw := "{\n  \"meta\": {\n    \"query_time\": 0.039130201,\n    \"pagination\": {\n      \"offset\": 1345,\n      \"limit\": 5000,\n      \"total\": 1345\n    }\n  }\n}"

parsed := &MetaLicense{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), parsed)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(parsed.Meta.Pagination.Total) // Prints: 1345
```

Here's the types I used

```
type InLicense struct {
    Total int16 `json:"total,omitempty"`
}

type OutLicense struct {
    Pagination InLicense `json:"pagination,omitempty"`
}

type MetaLicense struct {
    Meta OutLicense `json:"meta,omitempty"`
}
```

As written your provided JSON has a extra `,` which makes your json unparsable (assuming you add the missing `}`'s too.

There are no lists in your JSON. Lists are denoted with the `[]` symbols. For your types to work it, your JSON would have to look like this:

```
{
  "meta": [{
    "query_time": 0.039130201,
    "pagination": [{
      "offset": 1345,
      "limit": 5000,
      "total": 1345
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information, going forward I will use the unmarshal method as well.

Comment: Also, you helped me figure out how to remove the "{ }" without using strings.Trim! Cheers.